# node-schedule- job is not not running on time

Tags: node.js, jobs

I am trying to run a job on every 2 minutes.I am using node-schedule. Here is the code-

```
var eventStatus = new cron.RecurrenceRule();
    eventStatus.minute = 1
    eventStatus.second = 59;
    cron.scheduleJob(eventStatus, function(){
    console.log(new Date(), 'The 30th second of the minute.');
    try{
    configurationHolder.JobScheduler.setEventStatus();
    }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    }
    });
```

This is not running on time. Sometimes it run multiple time at same instant and sometime it does not.

Can anybody help me in finding the reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
eventStatus.minute = 1
eventStatus.second = 59;
```

This mean that this one will run at 1m59s of every hours. If you want it to run every 2 minutes, it would be something like this

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/2 * * * *', function(){
    console.log('every 2 minutes');
});
```

Comment: I tried this cron, this is also not working. in my project, i created an event at 12:10pm and job should supposed to run at 12:10pm but it is 12:59pm and it still not run.

Comment: I tested mine. It works just fine; getting printed every 2 minutes.